# feed dialog android facebook

Tags: android, facebook

//i got this error sometimes when using the feed dialog on facebook :com.facebook.android.DialogError: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR
// sometime it works and sometimes it won't(loading appears the nothing happens) error is return on dialogerror function

here is the code :

```
                            Bundle parameters1 = new Bundle();


                            System.out.println("link>>>>"+srcLnk);
                            System.out.println("picture>>>>"+imagesrc);
                            System.out.println("name>>>>"+titlev);
                            System.out.println("description>>>>"+Html.fromHtml(url.toString()).toString());
                                 parameters1.putString("link",srcLnk);
                                 parameters1.putString("picture",imagesrc);
                                 parameters1.putString("name",titlev);
                                 parameters1.putString("caption","www.alsumaria.tv");
```

//                                   parameters1.putString("description",url.toString().replaceAll("\\n", "
"));
                                     parameters1.putString("description",Html.fromHtml(url.toString()).toString());
                                 facebook.dialog(activity,"feed",parameters1,

```
                                      new DialogListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                               Toast.makeText(activity, "Posted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                           }

                                           @Override
                                           public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                                               error.printStackTrace();
                                           }

                                           @Override
                                           public void onError(DialogError e) {
                                               e.printStackTrace();

                                           }

                                           @Override
                                           public void onCancel() {}
                                      }
                                );
```

Comment: Does this only happen with specific devices/Android versions?

Comment: no but i already fixed it with sharedialog instead